# what is the probability of number $7$ in $2^n$

Tags: number-theory

Consider $2^n$'s decimal expression, for example $$2^{100}=1267650600228229401496703205376$$, $7$ appeared $3$ times in all $31$ digits, the probability is $$p(7,2^{100},10) = 3/31$$.

Does $p(7,2^n,10)$ converge for $n$? If so what is it? Or as Jean's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3880447/what-is-the-probability-of-number-7-in-2n#comment8002903_3880447) suggested, is $2^n$ normal in base 10?

How about more general, is there a limit for $p(k,2^n,10)$, where $k = 0,1,2,\cdots,9$?

Going further, is there a limit for $p(k,m^n,10)$ where $m$ might be $3,4,...$, e.g. is there a limit for number $8$ in $3^n$?

Even further, could the base $10$ also be generalized?

Comment: A point of vocabulary: you want to establish whether $2^n$ is "normal to base 10" or not. [See this document](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1069786344).

Comment: In general, while the obvious guess is believed to be true, questions like these are very difficult and we have made little progress.

Answer (score 1):

> Not a 'real' answer, but it was too big for a comment.

I wrote and ran some [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica)-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
probs = DigitCount[#]/IntegerLength[#] &;
probs[2^(7500000000)]
```

Running the code gives:

```
Out[1]={28222047/282215621, 225792249/2257724968, 225764575/2257724968,
225766855/2257724968, 225747709/2257724968, 112889373/1128862484,
225767009/2257724968, 56441683/564431242, 112886709/1128862484,
225791299/2257724968}
```

So, we can see that:

```
In[2]:=N[%1]

Out[2]={0.100002, 0.100009, 0.0999965, 0.0999975, 0.099989, 0.100003,
0.0999976, 0.0999974, 0.1, 0.100008}
```

We can see that for the number $2^{7500000000}$ the probality for the digits $0$ to $9$ is approximaltely $10$%.

Comment: sounds this is something we can use but can't prove

Comment: @athos I think so too